# From Windows, Access a Web App running on Localhost on Ubuntu - Same LAN

Tags: windows, ubuntu, networking

I have a ruby application running on my Ubuntu machine on 192.168.1.254. I have a Windows computer on the same LAN and want to access this App. How can I do this?

Comment: Bind apache or whatever web server to that adress 192.168.1.254 or 0.0.0.0, open port 80 on ubuntu firewall, install mod_ruby enable cgi type for example: http://192.168.1.254/cgi-bin/yourscript.rb in your browser at windows pc? I think you should provide more info. What did you try till now? What is the main problem? Running ruby mod at webserver? Accessing webserver? What kind of skript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Putty from the Windows box and configure a tunnel. This will enable you to connect to a port on localhost that is actually connected to somewhere else (localhost port of ruby app on 192.168.1.254)

You want something like:

[image: putty ssh tunnels]

For more info look at the -L option in `man ssh`.